# In ViewPager a page loses content when selection is far away from it by 2

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I created a ViewPager that is dynamically built.

In one of the pages lies a [PDFViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer), that behaves strangely, but the problem and the question, I think, relate to my ViewPager implementation and not in the PDFViewer. Anyway, I also tried the same code with ImageViews, TextViews, and any other kind of stuff, but only that one gives me that behaviour.

The problem is:

- The PDFViewer displays perfectly when shown the first time, and this does not depend on which page number is.
- If I slide away by one page back or forward, and then go back to the PDFViewer, everything is fine.
- If I slide away by **two or more** pages back or forward, and then go back to the PDFViewer, the content of the view is completely empty

It looks as if a memory cache was thrown away and the PDFViewer was not notified to refresh when was needed to show its content again.

I debugged this but didn't find anything useful.

UPDATE:
I found that - as expected - the view is destroyed when the selected page is 2 away from it.
is it a normal behaviour? How can I disable this behaviour?

This is part of my code, but I suppose that there's nothing special in it:

```
    showAdapter = new ShowAdapter();
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.show_viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(showAdapter);

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    FrameLayout v0 = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_empty, null);
    showAdapter.addView(v0, 0);
    showAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

   // ... list of similar adds and notifies
```

The Adapter. Maybe there's something wrong there? Maybe should I call some refresh or notify from inside here?

```
public class ShowAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
private ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

@Override public int getItemPosition (Object object)
{
    int index = views.indexOf (object);
    if (index == -1)
        return POSITION_NONE;
    else
        return index;
}
@Override public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position)
{
    View v = views.get (position);
    container.addView (v);
    return v;
}
@Override public void destroyItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
{
    container.removeView (views.get (position));
}
@Override public int getCount ()
{
    return views.size();
}
@Override public boolean isViewFromObject (View view, Object object)
{
    return view == object;
}
public int addView (View v)
{
    return addView (v, views.size());
}
public int addView (View v, int position)
{
    views.add (position, v);
    return position;
}
public int removeView (ViewPager pager, View v)
{
    return removeView (pager, views.indexOf (v));
}
public int removeView (ViewPager pager, int position)
{
    pager.setAdapter (null);
    views.remove (position);
    pager.setAdapter (this);

    return position;
}
public View getView (int position)
{
    return views.get (position);
}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the problem by forcing the viewPager not to destroy the far views with this:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```

Where obviously 5 is a large enough limit to keep them all active.
Still, this is quite a hack and doesn't fix very well my problem, so I'll open another more detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the content on resume

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
               super.onResume();
       // Refresh and reload content here 

    }
```

Comment: Uhm... The problem arises when the page is changed, not when the activity is paused, I don't think that this would fix...

Comment: I know same problem occur with me . You need to override in fragment onResume method

Comment: Override fragment onResume only . Not in activity

Comment: Oh I see so you mean the onResume of PDFViewer? Let me check this out

Comment: Yep but the problem is that PDFView extends RelativeLayout... and there is no Fragment inside of it :(